# Undefined reference to static member of class template referenced from static instance

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, undefined-reference, static-order-fiasco

Please take a look at the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

template <int N> class Object;
template <int N> class Thing;

template <int N>
class Factory {
    private:
        using FuncPtr = Object<N>*(*)(Thing<N>*);
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, FuncPtr> map;
    public:
        static void insertInMap (const std::string& tag, FuncPtr funcPtr) {
            map.emplace (tag, funcPtr);
        }
};
template <int N> 
std::unordered_map<std::string, typename Factory<N>::FuncPtr> Factory<N>::map;

// won't compile on GCC 4.8.1:
//template <> std::unordered_map<std::string, typename Factory<0>::FuncPtr> Factory<0>::map;  

template <int N> struct Object {};

struct Blob : Object<0> {
    static Blob prototype;
    Blob() {Factory<0>::insertInMap ("Blob", Blob::create);}
    Blob (Thing<0>*) {/* */}
    static Object<0>* create (Thing<0>* x) {return new Blob(x);}
};
Blob Blob::prototype;  // Calls up Factory<0>::insertInMap during compile time, but crashes when run.

int main()
{
}
```

So it appears that `Blob Blob::prototype;` crashes because `Factory<0>::map` has not been instantiated yet, so I try to instantiate it with the line:

```
template <> std::unordered_map<std::string, typename Factory<0>::FuncPtr> Factory<0>::map;
```

but it won't compile (with GCC 4.8.1):

```
C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsGlFeV.o:Practice.cpp:(.text$_ZN7FactoryILi0E
E11insertInMapERKSsPFP6ObjectILi0EEP5ThingILi0EEE[__ZN7FactoryILi0EE11insertInMa
pERKSsPFP6ObjectILi0EEP5ThingILi0EEE]+0x14): undefined reference to `Factory<0>:
:map'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The compiler *crashes* ??? Or you just get a bunch of compiler error messages ?

Comment: [Compiles fine here too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9bc1a436fa0cd4c). The executable crashes though - perhaps that's what the OP means ?

Comment: When you comment in the uncommented line then you get a single *link* error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25824e6fba8f074d

Comment: I posted the compiling error message when I uncomment that line I mentioned.  Without that line, it compiles, but crashes when I run it.

Comment: As already noted above, that's a *link* error.

Comment: @ Paul.  Ok, but I still don't know what the solution is then.

Comment: @PiotrS. I'm kind of sleeping today, right :)

Comment: @prestokeys: the link error tells you everything you need to know, but see also the hint from texasbruce above.

Comment: The *"fun"* of static initialisation order...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *specializing* `Factory<N>::map` for `<0>`, just explicitly *instantiate* the entire class:

```
template class Factory<0>;
```

in place of `//template <> ...`

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cb300eac0a47953)

---

**UPDATE**

For Visual Studio, which seems to still fail to initialize the static field even the template is explicitly instantiated before first usage, you can alternatively specialize the entire class:

```
template <>
class Factory<0> {
    private:
        typedef Object<0>*(*FuncPtr)(Thing<0>*);
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, FuncPtr> map;
    public:
        static void insertInMap (const std::string& tag, FuncPtr funcPtr) {
            map.emplace (tag, funcPtr);
    }
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, Factory<0>::FuncPtr> Factory<0>::map;
```

or define the field for `Factory<0>` (though I don't know why VS accepts that and does not trigger an error, as the syntax is not valid):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Factory<0>::FuncPtr> Factory<0>::map;
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a14657a724a0c0ae)

Comment: Yes, this solution works with GCC.  But when I run it on Visual Studio 2013, it still crashes because of reading nullptr.  Which compiler is bugged here?  Is there a solution that works on both? Because I check my compiling with both compilers.

Comment: Static order initialization fiasco only happens on static variables in different compilation units

Comment: Ok, I will specialize all the different Factory classes individually, like I originally did, and try to use private inheritance to capture the common stuff.  VS2013 actually accepts my original code above (with the commented-out line used), but I knew the code is wrong anyway. Thanks.