# Deducing Class Type from String

Tags: c++, string, templates, reflection, introspection

As described in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582456), you can determine a derived object from a string, as long as you know the base type. I wanted to make the code more flexible by making the BaseFactory a template, which results in the following compilable code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>


///Reflect and Register
#define MyType(BASE, TYPE) \
    static Registerer<BASE, TYPE> reg

#define Register(BASE, TYPE) \
    Registerer<BASE, TYPE> TYPE::reg(#TYPE)

template<class B>
class Factory
{
public:
    static B* from(const std::string& name)
    {
        return mapping[name];//should check if its a member
    }
    static void add(const std::string& name, B* instance)
    {
        mapping[name] = instance;
    }
    static std::map<std::string, B*> mapping;
};
template<class B>
std::map<std::string, B*> Factory<B>::mapping = std::map<std::string, B*>();


template<class B, class D>
class Registerer
{
public:
    Registerer(const std::string& name)
    {
        Factory<Base>::add(name, new D);//actually add
    }
};
///Deduce and Register


///Class examples implementing Registration
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        name = "Base Class";
    }
    const std::string& getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
protected:
    std::string name;
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1()
    {
        name = "I am type 1.\n";
    }
    MyType(Base, Derived1);
};
Register(Base, Derived1);
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2()
    {
        name = "I am type 2.\n";
    }
    MyType(Base, Derived2);
};
Register(Base, Derived2);
///Class examples implementing Registration


int main()
{
    std::string typeString1 = "Derived1";
    std::string typeString2 = "Derived2";

    std::cout << Factory<Base>::from(typeString1)->getName();
    std::cout << Factory<Base>::from(typeString2)->getName();

    return 0;
}
```

However, this code crashes, apparently because Factory::mapping does not get instantiated in time for when Registerer calls add. As described in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825408), there is a solution, which is to add the line

```
template class Factory<Base>;
```

which does not fix the problem in Visual Studio, which is what I'm using. The other possibility is to explicitly make a new class, but the whole point was to use a template in the first place. So I came up with this:

```
template<class B>
class Factory
{
public:
    static B* from(const std::string& name, B* instance = NULL)
    {
        static std::map<std::string, B*> mapping;
        if(instance != NULL)
        {
            mapping[name] = instance;
            return NULL;
        }
        else//should check if name is in map first
            return mapping[name];
    }
};
```

Which works since the mapping variable is initialized the first time the function is called. The unfortunate part is the if check.

I'm trying to find solutions that:

1. Does not use a single function in Factory to simulate two.
2. A way to register a class with a single line instead of two.
3. The ability to force a child class of Base to register itself, to prevent a user accidentally not registering it.

Comment: It looks like you started trying to make a generic derived object factory, and ended up with a directory of instantiated variables.

Comment: @JamesRoot I did, but it accomplishes the same thing for me, and is logically equivalent.